# Form data on load of Blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

It seems that I have looked everywhere and tried everything and I can not get this to work, any help would be much appreciated! I am using Blueimp's jQuery File Upload. I have changed the UploadHandler.php in the following ways to make this upload work with multiple records and places within my system. I am using PHP and MySQL.

Added to handle_file_upload function so that the file path, file name, file type, file size, the record type, and the "job number" is uploaded to a table I created in MySQL for each different file.

```
$file->upload_to_db = $this->add_file($job_num, $recordtype, $file_path, $filename, $type, $file_size);
```

This job number is sent to the page (with the file upload) as a get variable as well as a hidden form field to send to the Handler when adding a file. The add_file function I added is as follows:

```
function add_file($job_num, $recordtype, $filepath, $filename, $filetype, $filesize)
{
    $filepath = addslashes($filepath);
    $insert_query = $this->query("INSERT INTO fileupload (job_num, recordtype, file_path, file_name, file_type, file_size) VALUES ('".$job_num."','".$recordtype."','".$filepath."','".$filename."','".$filetype."','".$filesize."')");
    return $insert_query;
}
```

The query function:

```
protected function query($query) {
    $database = $this->options['database'];
    $host = $this->options['host'];
    $username = $this->options['username']; 
    $password = $this->options['password'];
    $Link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$Link){
        die( mysql_error() );
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);
    if (!$db_selected){
        die( mysql_error() );
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($Link);
    return $result;
}
```

I have a function for the delete as well. Now, this all works fine. Every file I add is saved and the path is stored in the database. From here I had to find a way to only show the files uploaded for that record instead of showing all files for every record. I modified the get function:

```
public function get($print_response = true) {
      if ($print_response && isset($_GET['download'])) {
        return $this->download();
    }
    $uploads = $this->query_db();
    return $this->generate_response($uploads, $print_response);
}
```

The query_db function:

```
public function query_db() {
    $uploads_array = array();
    // error_log("Job Num: ".$this->job_num."\n\n",3,"error_log.txt");
    $select_result = $this->query("SELECT * FROM fileupload WHERE job_num=423424");
    while($query_results = mysql_fetch_object($select_result))
    {   
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->id = $query_results->id;
        $file->name = $query_results->file_name;
        $file->size = $query_results->file_size;
        $file->type = $query_results->file_type;
        $file->url = "filepath_to_url/".$query_results->file_name;
        $file->thumbnail_url = "filepath_to_thumbnail/".$query_results->file_name;
        $file->delete_url = "";
        $file->delete_type = "DELETE";
        array_push($uploads_array,$file);
    }
    return $uploads_array;
}
```

Where the filepath is correct on my system. This, again, works just fine. But as you can see from the query in the query_db function I have the job_num hard coded. I need a way to get this when the first page is loaded. I have looked for a way to do this and nothing has worked. When I submit/add other files I can use the $_REQUEST['job_num'] to get it, but not when the page is loaded. I am not very familiar with OOP PHP so some of this is new to me.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following the issue since is seems you posted a bunch of working code and didn't really foucs down on what wasn't working.  From what I can tell, you have the job number in `$job_num`.  Why don't you just pass this value to your `query_db()` function?

Comment: $job_num is in the handle_file_upload function. That variable gets set only when uploading a file. To set that variable I used $_REQUEST['job_num'] from the hidden form field that is passed to the Class. I do not know how to pass this to the class when the page is actually loaded. I posted a lot of working code because everything I have works, it is just hard coded. I need a way to pass it when the page is first loaded, and I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you would probably want to add a `job_number` property to your class.  You could then set this value in your class when you call `add_file()`  like this

```
function add_file($job_num, $recordtype, $filepath, $filename, $filetype, $filesize)
{
    $this->job_number = $job_num;
    $filepath = addslashes($filepath);
    $insert_query = $this->query("INSERT INTO fileupload (job_num, recordtype, file_path, file_name, file_type, file_size) VALUES ('".$job_num."','".$recordtype."','".$filepath."','".$filename."','".$filetype."','".$filesize."')");
    return $insert_query;
}
```

You could then reference this job number in your `query_db()` method like this:

```
public function query_db() {
    $uploads_array = array();
    // error_log("Job Num: ".$this->job_num."\n\n",3,"error_log.txt");
    $select_result = $this->query("SELECT * FROM fileupload WHERE job_num=" . $this->job_number);
    while($query_results = mysql_fetch_object($select_result))
    {   
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->id = $query_results->id;
        $file->name = $query_results->file_name;
        $file->size = $query_results->file_size;
        $file->type = $query_results->file_type;
        $file->url = "filepath_to_url/".$query_results->file_name;
        $file->thumbnail_url = "filepath_to_thumbnail/".$query_results->file_name;
        $file->delete_url = "";
        $file->delete_type = "DELETE";
        array_push($uploads_array,$file);
    }
    return $uploads_array;
}
```

Note I did not take data sanitation into account in my code samples.  You would need to do that as well to prevent against SQL injection.  In reality, you should really look at using the `mysqli_*` functions as the `mysql_*` are deprecated.  You should also probably pass the database connection into you class you you have it available to all areas of the class (like the `add_file` method where it would be nice to escape the job number before setting it in the object).

Comment: How do I add the $job_num property to the class? In index.php (same directory as UploadHandler.php) there is the require for the handler and $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(); I have no idea how this page is called but when I comment out those two lines nothing works. I tried moving them to the script that has the file upload on it so that I could do new UploadHandler($job_num) but that does not work. I get a "No database selected" error.

Comment: I did a find in files search for index.php and it is no where to be found yet somehow it is getting called and that is where the object is being created. So how do I add properties if I can not add them in index.php

Comment: You said you added new methods to this class right?  Where did you add those methods and copy and paste the code you posted from?  That class is where you would add the additional property.

Comment: I guess I am uncertain as to what you mean by property. I have $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($job_num); as well as in the __construct. But $job_num is empty in index.php as I do not understand how blueimp has this set up.

Comment: I property is a variable stored in a class. If you are already passing the $job_num to the constructor just set `$this->job_number` in the constructor and reference it where needed within that class instance. I know nothing about BlueImp or what you are working with and you haven't shown code in index.php to where one might understand how that is populated.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this. The code in index is `require_once('UploadHandler.php'); $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();` But again I have no idea how this is called or where index.php is included at so I can not add `$job_num` here. I already have `$this->job_num` set but since `$job_num` is empty when passed it is not set to anything. Thank you for your help, I suppose I should have been more direct in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful

```
protected function get_file_objects() {

    $user_id = $this->options['session_id'];
    $files = $this->query("SELECT yourname FROM yourname WHERE yourname='$user_id'");
    $files_array=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($files)){
        array_push($files_array,$row['yourname']);
    }
    return array_values( array_filter( array_map(
        array($this, 'get_file_object'),
        $files_array
    ) ) );
}
```